# What is the complexity of this function with nested loops?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of this code?

```
public class test5{
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++) {
         System.out.print ("*");
      }
   System.out.println();
   }

  for (int i = n; i>=1; i--) {
      for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++) {
         System.out.print ("*");
      }
   System.out.println();
   }
}
```

}

My assumption is that it will take O(n^2) operations because n*(n/2) + n*(n/2).
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, a tight upper asymptotic bound for both the first and second nested loop blocks—say `T_A(n)` and `T_B(n)`, respectively—is `O(n^2)`, and hence the function as a whole runs as `O(n^2)`, asymptotically.

You can analyze this in detail using Sigma notation to count the number of basic operations in the inner loop blocks for each of the nested loop blocks `T_A(n)` and `T_B(n)`:

[image]

Where we've treated the `System.out.print ("*");` operation as basic operation.