# I calculated this simple loop complexity incorrectly, how to calculate it correctly?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The loop is

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++)
  for (int j = 0 ; j<i ; j++)
   count++;
```

I calculated the complexity = n * n(n+1)/2 so it will be n^3
but the answer is n^2 why?

Comment: What is the basis for your calculation? Just by intuition, even if `j` went to `n` rather than `i`, then that would be a textbook n^2. So if it goes less, it can't possibly be more than n^2.

Comment: it is definitely clear that complexity is < O(n²) . how did you find that cubic complexity?

Comment: @Rotem beat me to it

Comment: @OP If `j` went up to `n`, what would your assumed calculation be?  Would it still be `O(n^3)`?  A *triple* nested loop, where each loop goes up to `n` would be `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the complexity of this function with nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913439/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-function-with-nested-loops). See the derivation for `T_A(n)` in the accepted answer (same kind of loop as yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check that `j` goes from 0 to `i`. As `i` goes from 0 to `n`, we have:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n =
1 + 2 + ... + n =
(n + 1) * (n / 2) = (n² + n)/2 = O(n²)
```

There is an extra `n` multiplying the answer in your calculation that comes from nowhere and this is the problem in your complexity.